# Altering sun azimuth on shaded relief LiDAR maps in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, dem, lidar, hillshade

I have a LiDAR map and want to change the view so that the ground shadow is manipulated (looking for archaeological anomalies). I think it is the sun angle that I need to alter but I don't know how.

I am running on Windows 7 with QGIS 2.4 downloaded. I am new to QGIS and I am struggling with such task.

Comment: Hi @Caroline and welcome to the GIS Stack Exchange. Can you give us some more details? For example, are you dealing with the LiDAR point cloud or an interpolated raster grid DEM? If it is a grid you have and you want the azimuth of the DEM surface, use an Aspect tool.

Comment: Thanks for answering....I havent a clue what I have !!??  It is a lidar image apparently taken from a plane with the vegetation ect stripped out and is in a raster file. Could you explain the difference between the 2 you have mentioned? I'm beginning to think this is going to be way past my capabilities but hope not

Comment: Having now read the reply from martin f I now realize that it is not the azimuth that I should be altering but the sun angle. So, with that revelation ....please....how do I do that !!

Comment: What file extension does your LIDAR data have? For example it might be 'filename.asc' or 'filename.las'.

Comment: As you can see I am very new to this....  It says XML doc   and the end of the file name says tif.aux

Comment: Does the file load into QGIS when you go Layer -> Add Raster Layer?

Comment: Yes it downloads via the Raster layer in QGIS

Answer (score 4):

It appears that your LIDAR data is in the form of a gridded digital elevation model (DEM) that loads into QGIS without difficulty. I'd suggest that you attempt to render the DEM as shaded relief using the following method (for reasons I'll explain later).

So, load the DEM into QGIS and then click on 'Processing' in the menu at the top of the screen and select 'Toolbox'. In the window that appears go 'GDAL/OGR' -> '[GDAL] Analysis' and click on 'Hillshade'. This will pop-up a dialogue box similar to that shown in the illustration. For a first attempt at rendering I would leave the default values in the box unchanged and press 'Run'. Assuming that this works as it should you should now have a shaded-relief rendering of your DEM on your screen.

You can now experiment using different values, for example you could increase the Z-factor, change the azimuth of the light or change the altitude of the light. To begin with I would keep the 'azimuth of the light' values between about 300 and 360 degrees (lighting the view from, say, the south can produce shading that makes hills appear as valleys and vice versa).

As you create them the rendered images will be stacked on the screen, so by ticking or unticking them in the layers panel it will be possible to make comparisons between them very quickly. When you find a view that fits your bill you can save it as an image (fill in the details under 'Output file').

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here are some general concepts and terms relevant to your case.
They are not QGIS-specific because I don't know QGIS.

In "raw" form, lidar data are a dense, irregularly distributed set of X,Y,Z points called a *point cloud*.

In "reduced" form, they're often in a regularly distributed grid (or *raster*) of Z points (X,Y being implied by location within the grid). The grid is often called a *DEM* (digital elevation model).

Another "reduced" form is an irregularly distributed triangular network of X,Y,Z points called a *TIN* (triangular irregular network).

A generic term for a DEM or TIN is a *DTM* (digital terrain model). You can consider the *model*, especially in a visual form, as being the same as a *map*. Ideally, you should be able to view this map in different ways for different effect:

Vary the *azimuth* (or *orientation*), i.e., the rotation about a vertical axis.

Vary the *tilt* (or *inclination*), i.e., the rotation about a horizontal axis. This tilt has two components -- either an X-tilt and Y-tilt, or a total tilt and its direction.

Note that the sign and direction of azimuths and tilts depend on whether they refer to the map/model or you the observer. Also note that tilt is usually measured from vertical down to horizon while inclination is measured from horizon up to vertical.

Vary the *sun angle*, i.e., the orientation and inclination of the source of illumination.